# UDP broadcast client in Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am using UDP broadcast for interservice communication  The server is in Python and I can see the UDP messages using this code:

```
import sys
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 9002

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    try:
        message = s.recv(8192)
        print("Got data: " + message)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

I can run as many of these clients simultaneously as I want on the same machine.

I'm trying to implement a similar client in Java using the DatagramSocket class, but I keep getting an "address already in use" error.  Evidently I need to construct it differently than I am currently:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(broadcastPort);
```

Is it possible to get the same behavior as the Python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// create an unbound socket
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);

// make it possible to bind several sockets to the same port
socket.setReuseAddress(true);

// might not be necessary, but for clarity
socket.setBroadcast(true);

socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9002));
```

The null argument to the constructor is the key here. That wisdom is hidden in the second paragraph of the javadoc for the `DatagramSocket(SocketAddress bindAddress)` constructor:

> if the address is null, creates an **unbound** socket.

Comment: That did it, thank you.  Nice to find that hidden in the javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Address already in use probably means you haven't properly terminated your programs. If you're using Eclipse, make sure you check all your open consoles and terminate all of them. (Top right corner, blue box - click it and it'll show all running programs)

In Eclipse, just because you "run" your program again, it doesn't terminate the previous one(s).

Another possible issue is that you may be using the same port as your python server. 2 Applications can't claim the same port, so just change the port number if that is the case.

**Edit: Use a** `MulticastSocket`**.**

Comment: I'm running from the command line.  I can run as many of the Python clients to listen on the UDP broadcast as I want.  I'm wondering how to configure Java the same way.

Comment: @Aify Multicast and Broadcast are *not* the same things

Comment: @forty-two But a MulticastSocket and a DatagramSocket are the same thing, except that a MulticastSocket has more methods. You can unicast with a MulticastSocket.

Comment: @EJP Ok, but does it help when you want to receive a broadcast packet?

Comment: @forty-two It helps in this question because it automatically sets SO_REUSEADDR. One line instead of your three.